# How to know if MySQLnd is the active driver?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

Maybe it's an obvious question, but I want to be sure.

How can i know if it MySQLnd is the active driver?

I'm runing PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.1.37.
In phpinfo() mysqlnd is listed but only with this I can't be sure if I'm using MySQLnd or the old driver...

Extract of phpinfo() output

```
mysql
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $ 

mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $
Active Persistent Links     0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    26 

mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version     mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $ 

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $
```

I'm using PDO, and PDO driver says mysql...

Comment: Yes the "PDO drivers" row says "mysql", but below that it says "Client API version  **mysqlnd** 5.0.5-dev - 081106 - $Revision: 1.3.2.27 $"........

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> **Warning!** This method is unreliable and does not work since PHP 8.1

If you are accessing via `mysqli`, this should do the trick:

```
<?php
$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');

if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}
```

To detect if its the active `PDO` driver, create your MySQL PDO object then:

```
if (strpos($pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION), 'mysqlnd') !== false) {
    echo 'PDO MySQLnd enabled!';
}
```

Comment: It looks like I'm having a similar problem and when i try to use the getAttribute function i get this error: Call to a member function `getAttribute()` on a non-object. It appears that mysqlnd is enabled but i can't use `get_result()` either, any idea?

Comment: This function isn't robust enough since it will give a false negative if `mysqli` itself isn't even available. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22499259/632951 for a better version.

Comment: @Inspire, And another possible issue is of course if someone else defines that function even while you don't have mysqlnd. Then you would get a false positive.

Comment: @cookinggood The variable `$pdo` must be an instance of `PDO`. That is, you must assign `new PDO(...)` to it, first.

Comment: This is wrong. As @Tim-Groeneveld suggest check for a `mysqlnd` specific function.

Comment: @AntonioBardazzi  - Tim appears to be (for now) wrong: [mysqli-fetch-all doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) explicitly says **"MySQL Native Driver Only .. Available only with mysqlnd"**.  I read that as saying that checking for `mysqli_fetch_all` **does** only succeed when you are using mysqlnd. It is a valid test - at least for now; in theory that could change in future.

Comment: .. though to clarify, any check of a *mysqli* function only tells us whether *mysqli* is using `mysqlnd`; to know whether `PDO` is using `mysqlnd`, use the second code snippet in this answer.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve PHP 8.1 supports `mysqli_fetch_all` when linked against `libmysqlclient`. The correct way to test for mysqlnd is with my method.

Comment: As mentioned by others, this answer is no longer valid. Tim Groeneveld's https://stackoverflow.com/a/22499259/1045774 should be marked as the accepted answer

Answer (score 44):

Checking for `mysqli_fetch_all` does not really describe wether you are using `mysqlnd`. Rather, it says that you have the [mysqli extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) enabled.

MySQLi is simply an updated version of the `mysql` extension that was provided in earlier versions of PHP.

> The `mysql` extension, the `mysqli` extension and the `PDO MySQL driver` can each be individually configured to use either
> libmysqlclient or mysqlnd

This code:

```
<?php
$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');

if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}
```

not echoing nothing suggests that you don't have mysqli compiled/enabled/installed, and might be using the older `mysql` extension.

A better way to check for mysqli with mysqlnd vs mysql with libmysqlclient is to do this:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) {
    echo "- MySQL <b>is installed</b>.<br>";
} else  {
    echo "- MySQL <b>is not</b> installed.<br>";
}

if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
    echo "- MySQLi <b>is installed</b>.<br>";
} else {
    echo "- MySQLi <b>is not installed</b>.<br>";
}

if (function_exists('mysqli_get_client_stats')) {
    echo "- MySQLnd driver is being used.<br>";
} else {
    echo "- libmysqlclient driver is being used.<br>";
}
```

This works because [mysqlnd provides three additional functions that work only when mysqlnd is used as the driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php).

Finally, the PDO check needs to have the `$pdo` variable defined first.

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "password";
$dbName = "database";

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
if (strpos($pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION), 'mysqlnd') !== false) {
    echo '- PDO MySQLnd <b>is enabled</b>.<br>';
} else {
    echo '- PDO MySQLnd <b>is not enabled</b>.<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: sentence in C:\Dev\Billing\checkmysqlnd.php on line 8 .. either need to put `$sentence = ""` at top or have the first `if / else` changed from `.=` to `=` .. still works just throws that error

Comment: Re *"Checking for mysqli_fetch_all does not really describe wether you are using mysqlnd .."*.  Actually [mysqli-fetch-all doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) explicitly says **"MySQL Native Driver Only .. Available only with mysqlnd"**.  I read that as saying that checking for `mysqli_fetch_all` **does** describe whether you are using mysqlnd.

Comment: ... though reading your answer further, I realize (any of the *mysqli* checks) only tells us whether **mysqli** is using `mysqlnd`; for `PDO` it is the last part of your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The driver (libmysql or mysqlnd) is choosen at compile-time, and each one of those two can be specified independatly for mysql, mysqli, and pdo_mysql.

Here are the three configure options that correspond to mysqlnd :

```
  --with-mysql[=DIR]      Include MySQL support.  DIR is the MySQL base
                          directory.  If mysqlnd is passed as DIR,
                          the MySQL native driver will be used [/usr/local]
  --with-mysqli[=FILE]    Include MySQLi support.  FILE is the path
                          to mysql_config.  If mysqlnd is passed as FILE,
                          the MySQL native driver will be used [mysql_config]
  --with-pdo-mysql[=DIR]    PDO: MySQL support. DIR is the MySQL base directoy
                                 If mysqlnd is passed as DIR, the MySQL native
                                 native driver will be used [/usr/local]
```

In your case, the "Client API version" is "mysqlnd 5.0.5-dev" for both mysql, mysqli, and pdo_mysql.

So it seems you ahre using mysqlnd in either three cases.

In the case of PDO, you have the MySQL driver installed -- and that one is compiled based on mysqlnd.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood your last sentence. "MySQL driver installed -- and that one is compiled based on mysqlnd." It means it's using mysqlnd or not?
BTW I'm ussing debian, I don't want to compile and lose the possibility to use apt-get

Comment: PDO is using "drivers" : one for SQLite, one for Postgre, one for mssql, one for MySQL, ... And, for MySQL, that driver can be compiled to use either libmysql or mysqlnd ;; in your case, it says "mysqlnd"

Comment: @PascalMARTIN, Are you saying that the value to the right of the key `PDO drivers` (in his phpinfo output) can never be **mysqli** and can only be **mysql** (, postgre, sqllite, etc)?

Comment: @Pacerier - given that `PDO` is an *alternative to* `mysqli`, that surely must be the case; it would not be meaningful to have "PDO built on mysqli", right?

Answer (score 8):

This is what I was looking for

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded('mysqlnd')) {
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysqlnd` may be loaded and yet not be used by mysql(i)/pdo_mysql

Answer (score 3):

Maybe check if [these settings](http://php.net/mysqlnd.config.php) exist? phpinfo() renders them differently from other ini settings for some reason. Works for 5.4, not sure about 5.3.

```
ini_get('mysqlnd.debug') !== false
```

Comment: It will return empty `string(0) ""` if mysqlnd installed, but may not active (PHP8.0)

Answer (score 1):

phpinfo() in the beginning lists the "Configure Command" used to compile PHP.

As they state in other answers mysqlnd is 1 (the default) of 2 choices during the php install/compile process.

My phpinfo Configure Command for 7.0.33 is:

'./configure' '--prefix=/opt/php70' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dbase' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-intl' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sqlite-utf8' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-freetype-dir' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mssql' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl' '--with-pdo-mysql=/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr' '--with-pgsql=/usr' '--with-pdo-sqlite' '--with-png-dir' '--with-pspell' '--with-sqlite' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-tidy' '--with-unixODBC' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl' '--with-zlib'

Note --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '

and --enable-mysqlnd' ' (Not in this one but a readout on a 5.6 php build)

--with-mysqli= is pointing to a directory meaning it is using libmysqlclient
If it was mysqlnd instead then it is using the native driver.

For more info on this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php

(I know this is way old however this knowledge would have saved me hours of tech support debate and I seen this first.)