# PHP: How to check and install mysqlnd_qc

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use this plugin because can cache the query results. But even reading the docs at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/apis-php-mysqlnd-qc.setup.html
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.setup.php

still confused. Does it mean it comes with PHP 5.4 by default? If not, how I can I check if it's installed from CentOS using a command line? Also, how can I check if it's installed on my local PC running XAMPP with PHP 5.4?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a PECL extension. It is not bundled with PHP. [Read the instructions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-qc.installation.php)

Comment: Already did, still confused, hence the question :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, none of the mysqlnd plugins are installed by default.

I've tried installing one of the mysqlnd plugins (in my case it was mysqlnd_ms), but I've had limited success. I concluded that I needed to build both the mysqlnd plugin *and* PHP itself from source to get it to work.

At that point I lost interest, because none of my clients are willing to build PHP from source for their environments. They want to use binary installs, preferably from a yum package repo.

I don't think these plugins will catch on as viable tools until they are installable in a more convenient way, for example through PECL or Composer.

Comment: It looks like it's available for PECL http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.intro.php but still confused

Comment: Looks like PHP 5.4 has it installed by default http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/ just wondering how to test it.

Comment: Using this tutor, looks like PHP 5.4 has it installed

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on this doc, PHP 5.4 has installed MySQLnd by default

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

and to test it using this answer

[How to know if MySQLnd is the active driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475701/how-to-know-if-mysqlnd-is-the-active-driver)