# phpinfo says MySQLnd is the active driver or am i confused

Tags: mysql, pdo, php, mysqlnd

When i try to use the getAttribute function i get this error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object. It appears that mysqlnd is enabled but i can't use get_result() either, any idea?

This has really been bothering me lately. On another post @inspire answered correctly but doesn't work for me. You can find that here: [How to know if MySQLnd is the active driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475701/how-to-know-if-mysqlnd-is-the-active-driver)

When i echo this:

```
<?php
$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');

if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}
```

nothing happens at all, so apparently it's not enabled even though my phpinfo() says it's enabled?

To detect if its the active PDO driver, create your MySQL PDO object then:

```
if (strpos($pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION), 'mysqlnd') !== false) {
    echo 'PDO MySQLnd enabled!';
}
```

When i try this i get call to member function getAttribute() on a non object..

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know if MySQLnd is the active driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475701/how-to-know-if-mysqlnd-is-the-active-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Checking for `mysqli_fetch_all` does not really describe wether you are using `mysqlnd`. Rather, it says that you have the [mysqli extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) enabled.

MySQLi is simply an updated version of the `mysql` extension that was provided in earlier versions of PHP.

> The `mysql` extension, the `mysqli` extension and the `PDO MySQL driver` can each be individually configured to use either
> libmysqlclient or mysqlnd

This code:

```
<?php
$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');

if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}
```

not echoing nothing suggests that you don't have mysqli compiled/enabled/installed with MySQLnd. Other clients inside PHP, such as the older mysql or the MySQL PDO driver may still be using mysqld.

A better way to check for mysqli with mysqlnd vs mysql with libmysqlclient is to do this:

```
<?php
$hasMySQL = false;
$hasMySQLi = false;
$withMySQLnd = false;

if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) {
    $hasMySQL = true;
    $sentence.= "(Deprecated) MySQL <b>is installed</b> ";
} else 
    $sentence.= "(Deprecated) MySQL <b>is not</b> installed ";

if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
    $hasMySQLi = true;
    $sentence.= "and the new (improved) MySQL <b>is installed</b>. ";
} else
    $sentence.= "and the new (improved) MySQL <b>is not installed</b>. ";

if (function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) {
    $withMySQLnd = true;
    $sentence.= "This server is using MySQLnd as the driver.";
} else
    $sentence.= "This server is using libmysqlclient as the driver.";

echo $sentence;
```

This works because [mysqlnd provides three additional functions that work only when mysqlnd is used as the driver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.stats.php). `mysqli_fetch_all` is one of these functions, however, it is best to not only check for a function that only shows if mysqli has been compilied with mysqlnd, but also a function that shows if mysqli is compiled at all.

This will allow you to present better error messages to the client.

Finally, the PDO check needs to have the `$pdo` variable defined first.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');
if (strpos($pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION), 'mysqlnd') !== false) {
    echo 'PDO MySQLnd enabled!';
}
```

Comment: surely you have read mysql_fetch_all manual page before issuing your authoritative statement?

Comment: @YourCommonSense "not echoing nothing suggests that you don't have mysqli compiled/enabled/installed, and might be using the older mysql extension." ... yes. What I mean to say is, checking for mysqli_fetch_all will check if mysqlnd is enabled for mysqli, but it does not actually check that mysqld is enabled on all MySQL client implementations available with PHP..

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in checking for the mysqlnd driver itself, either in phpinfo or in the code.

There is no point in checking for other API either. You have to check **if desired API** is based on mysqlnd, not other one. So, checking mysqli if you need PDO makes no sense.

To check PDO you have to have a PDO object first, **as error message suggests**.