# PHP - error Call to undefined method mysqli_result::store_result()

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am developing a PHP application and making a call to two stored procedure consecutively. 
When I am trying to do it giving the following error

```
     Command out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

I checked some solution and added the `store_result()` function but for now flagging another error is coming

```
     Call to undefined method mysqli_result::store_result()
```

Here a sample code of my application

```
        $sql         = "CALL get_count_posttype('POST')";
        $result      = $conn->query($sql);
        $postCount   = $result->data_seek(0);

        #i tried to use the following as some post suggested
        #i am getting the following error
        #Call to undefined method mysqli_result::store_result()
        //$result->store_result(); 
        //$result->free_result();

        $sql         = "CALL get_postview_for_admin($offset,$recLimit,'POST')";

        $result      = $conn->query($sql);

        # SQL error : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

        #current PHP Version 5.5.9
```

Comment: Do you have the MYSQLND driver installed? This method requires it.

Comment: @Barmar : I followed the this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475701/how-to-know-if-mysqlnd-is-the-active-driver `$mysqlnd = function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all');

if ($mysqlnd) {
    echo 'mysqlnd enabled!';
}` It is showing enabled.

Comment: I know this post is from a while ago, but it seems using `store_result()` with `query()` doesn't work. You need to prepare and execute the statement instead.