# Change hostname of SQL server SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a postgres SQL server set up in google cloud. The certificates that I downloaded for this have a hostname of the form: `project_name:instance_name`. However, the `:` messes with the syntax of an application that I want to connect to google cloud (`dbcrossbar`). Can I change the hostname of the certificates such that I can remove the `:`?

Comment: Is Kerberos authentication expected?  If so, try registering your Postgres SQL service principal name (SPN) in your domain (eg, `POSTGRES/project_name:instance_name@REALM`).  For non-domain systems, setup a local HOSTS file where `project_name:instance_name` targets the IP address of your Postgres SQL server.  If the application relies on PHP, there's a known bug in older versions.  [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260464/google-cloud-sql-ssl-fails-peer-certificate-validation)

Comment: @leeharvey1 thanks for the reply, I am not sure about the details of the authentication. I already solved an issue with the postgreSQL connection by adding project_name:instance_name with the corresponding ip adress to /etc/hosts. A postgreSQL connection to the cloud database with 'verify-full' (full SSL verification) works. The issue now is that I can't pass this hostname to the dbscrossbar application, a solution would probably to edit the source code but I'd rather have a cleaner fix as things are becoming very messy.