# mysql ->fetch_all() not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please shame me.  What's not right here?  I was hoping for something like ->fetch_all(Opt), a one liner, to place all the results in an array but couldn't make it work. This is what I wound up doing:

```
   $s = "select id, username from users"; 
   $conn = db_connect();
   $sth = $conn->prepare($s);
   $sth->execute();
   $sth->bind_result($id, $un);
   $ida = array();
   while ($sth->fetch()) {
     $ida[] = $id;
   }
```

I tried

`$r = $sth->fetch_all()` (tried assigning and not assigning a return value) both using and not using `->bind_result()`
but both failed.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, make sure that you have `mysqlnd` on your environment.

Then, to use `->fetch_all()`, you'll need to use [`->get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) method first.

Here's the sequence:

```
$s = "select id, username from users"; 
$conn = db_connect();
$sth = $conn->prepare($s);
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->get_result(); // get result first
$result = $data->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // then fetch all
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It's always one little thing and when you find out what it is ... doh!  Thanks again.

Comment: @user116032 sure glad this helped

Comment: just for closure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475701/how-to-know-if-mysqlnd-is-the-active-driver