# Cannot insert data using bind param

Tags: php

In my application I am using 2 php files where one contains all the funtions required for the application and the another is to retrive and send the data back to the user

My first php file is DB_Functions.php
which contains the following code

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

     private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

/**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
     public function storeUser($name,$sex,$dob,$email,$college,$password,$latitude,$longitude,$pass) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO CFLASH_USERS(Name, sex, dob, mail, college, password, latitude, longitude, pass, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
  $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $name, $sex, $dob, $email, $college, $password, $latitude, $longitude, $pass, $salt);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();


    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM CFLASH_USERS WHERE mail = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

 /**
 * Encrypting password
 * @param password
 * returns salt and encrypted password
 */
public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

/**
 * Decrypting password
 * @param salt, password
 * returns hash string
 */
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}

}

?>
```

My second php file Register.php contains

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

// receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['name'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$college = $_POST['college'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude']; 
$longitude  = $_POST['longitude']; 
$pass  = $_POST['pass'];

// create a new user
    $user = $db->storeUser($name, $sex, $dob, $email, $college ,$password, $latitude, $longitude, $pass);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["mail"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["Name"];
        $response["user"]["sex"] = $user["sex"];
        $response["user"]["dob"] = $user["dob"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["mail"];
        $response["user"]["college"] = $user["college"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

} else {

$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

My table structure is [image: table]

I am unable to insert the data into it. I have checked for the post meathod to be wrong but it not wrong. So I thought that there will be an error with bind_param(). Please let me know where the error is and a solution to rectify it.

Please explain me about "**Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()**"

Comment: `get_result()` is `Available only with mysqlnd.` Check [the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and make sure you have it

Comment: okay but that is present in if condition block so first bind param function should be executed which is not being executed or may be error is being generated at that line of code . So the if block is left unchecked so error is not being generated as Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result().

Comment: This driver isn't part of your code it is part of the server. Please check this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1475996/3140646) and check.

Comment: @karrthikdatabase if it doesn't executed your method will return false instead of throwing an error. [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.execute-returnvalues)

Comment: And the expression is better to listen on [`mysqli::$affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) for query like INSERT

Comment: @Chay22 its returing false.

Comment: You'd better see the link I gave on my first comment. If `$result = $stmt->execute()` is `true`, it will run the second query (which throwing you an error). If it `false`, your method will return also `false` which the error may come from your connection: `$this->conn`

Comment: I have tried for the another function login which is on the same php file DB_Functions.php which works absolutely fine. So i guess $this->conn is not the thing that cause error. I have tried login by using data which is inserted data into database with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Going to ask the obvious; are you filling in all form data? Since you are not initialising the variables, if they are empty bind_param won't accept a 'nothing' e.g. you'll need to do `$sex = (isset($_POST['sex']) ? $_POST['sex'] : "");`

Comment: I have tried that by initializing all the variables. Yet the same.

Comment: do `$sql = ''` then `echo` it and paste it directly into database and see what errors it throws up as it really isn't liking something and can be simple like spelling a column name wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing MySQLND. That method is only available with that driver.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: okay but that is present in if condition block so first bind param function should be executed which is not being executed or may be error is being generated at that line of code . So the if block is left unchecked so error is not being generated as Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result().

Comment: If the "if" clause is running, then that means your insert was successful (as per your code). Your question was regarding the get result error within that clause.

Comment: Are you saying that data is not being inserted to your database, despite the successful return of the statement execution?

Comment: Yes. The data is not being inserted.